# Show author bio box

Tags: posts, functions, loop

I have post page with author info. But I want to show author box info only if author has description. this is what i tried to do:

```
<?php if ( !empty(get_the_author_meta('description')) and !empty( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )) ):?>
    <div class="blog-article-author">
        //author info here
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I get an error:

> Can't use function return value in write context

for this part of code :

```
<?php if ( !empty(get_the_author_meta('description')) and !empty( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )) ):?>
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php: especially the note about PHP versions prior to 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
<?php
$authordesc = get_the_author_meta( 'description' );

if ( ! empty ( $authordesc ) ){ ?>
<div class="blog-article-author">
    //author info here...
</div>
<?php } ?>
```